# how to add html tags inside jsx (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to put a html tag inside a `span` to give some styling to a certain word. but it results in a plain text instead.

expectation:

abc **AND** xyz

what I get instead:

`abc <strong>AND</strong> xyz`

here's my code: ( [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-rain-tpzdrc?file=/src/App.js:0-308) )

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
        <span>{isLoading ? "abc" : `abc <strong>AND</strong> xyz`}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add it like this

```
<span>{isLoading ? "abc" : (<>abc <strong>AND</strong> xyz</>)}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your approach is that there are multiple adjacent DOM nodes. You can wrap them using a fragment:

```
<>abc <strong>AND</strong> xyz</>
```